# How do I output the the line that threw an error in a yaml unmarshal of a Docker-Compose.yml?

Tags: go, yaml, docker-compose

I'm writing some code that takes in a Docker-Compose.yml and unmarshals it into a struct.  I take the docker compose data in as a []byte.

```
    dockerData []byte
    var struct *struct
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(dockerData, &struct)
```

I run a lot of compose files through this process.  When errors are thrown, is there a way to output the line or section of the compose file that threw the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set flag on the logger to print out the line number

```
// main.go or config file

func init() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
}
```

You can find more of these flags [here](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants)

**handle the error**

```
dockerData []byte
var struct *struct
if err := yaml.Unmarshal(dockerData, &struct); err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}
```